# Authorization not working in swagger jersey, authorization checkbox is not showing

Tags: authorization, swagger-ui, jersey-2.0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNzc1.jpg)

```
List<AuthorizationScope> scopes = new ArrayList<AuthorizationScope>();
    scopes.add(new AuthorizationScope("pets", "Access all"));
    List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<GrantType>();
    ImplicitGrant implicitGrant = new ImplicitGrant(new LoginEndpoint("url"), "access_code");
    grantTypes.add(implicitGrant);
    AuthorizationType oauth = new OAuthBuilder().scopes(scopes).grantTypes(grantTypes).build();
    config.addAuthorization(oauth);
```

// i am using com.wordnik swagger-jaxrs_2.10 1.3.12

Comment: Any suggestion would be very helpful

Comment: I believe you will need to provide more details to get an answer here.